# Eighties post-apocalyptic book series with teleporters

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, teleportation

This is (I believe) a 1980s series of books set in the US after a nuclear war. The central characters I think are constant across the books although I only read one of them. One character is a weapons and explosives expert. The story features  secret US government teleportation technology developed before the war and located around the country in facilities like Cheyenne Mountain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[Deathlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathlands)" by James Axler comes to mind.

It has a main character, "Ryan Cawdor", who is a explosive and gun expert, a amnesiac doctor who actually is a time travel experiment. The story series features extensive teleporter networks hidden in bunkers over the United States, usually with a stockpile of supplies that were kept for post apocalyptic emergencies, and the series takes place after the world has experienced a nuclear war.

It's like *Fallout* with more science fiction, sex, violence, guns and explosive experts, mutants, and teleporters.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: yeah, that's the one! Thanks.

Comment: 125 books in the series now, wow.